# ko.observableArray() is very slow for 1000+ <div> elements

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

Please see my jsfiddler for the example.

http://jsfiddle.net/cYYEt/

If there is another way we should be binding/creating our array/etc that would work too.   I have solved this problem by either using a list or spans

Thanks!

JS

```
var mainViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;

    this.Items = ko.observableArray();

    this.init = function () {
        var itemsArray = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < 1300; i++){
            itemsArray.push("My value is: " + i);
        }
        self.Items(itemsArray );
    };
};

$(function () {
    myApp = new mainViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(myApp);
    myApp.init();
});​
```

HTML

```
<!-- ko foreach: Items -->
    <div data-bind="text: $data"></div>
<!-- /ko -->​
```

Comment: What is slow? im running IE9 and Opera and i can't find any slow or lagging part..

Comment: Chrome has trouble with the text nodes.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can get a decent improvement in Chrome by removing the text nodes surrounding your "template" like: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/RAfNv/.

```
<!-- ko foreach: Items --><div data-bind="text: $data"></div><!-- /ko -->
```

I think we will be looking to improve this in the core at some point.  We had looked at something like this before: https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/pull/709, but did not end up adding any changes at this point.

Comment: That's a serious improvement! That Fiddle took around 30 seconds before and with this change it's sub second (Chrome).

Comment: Interestingly enough, a fix may be coming to a browser near you; Performance is high in Chrome Canary 28.0.1500.3 regardless of whitespace. Does anyone have an idea _why_ this happens in today's WebKit? http://jsfiddle.net/cEK2x/2/